# Passing timestamp to psql from bash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, postgresql

I'm trying to script data copying in ruby/rails, and I'm running into issues when I try and filter by a timestamp.

Here is my query:

```
system(%Q{psql postgres://user:password@postgres --command '\copy (SELECT "id", "name" FROM some_table WHERE created_at > '2019-01-22 13:40') TO STDOUT WITH CSV'})
```

And I'm having issues with terminating strings and timestamps.

The query as is the error `\copy: parse error at end of line` I think because the timestamp and the whole query are both using single quotes.

If I try and wrap the timestamp in double quotes it thinks its a column name and throws and error.

If I try and wrap the whole query in double quotes and use single quoutes inside then I just get the names of the columns over and over, not the actual value.

I just can't figure out what the correct combination is.

Comment: Why not do something like 'AnyOldModel.connection.execute "a SQL Query"' .  Shelling out to psql, I've never needed to do that in 12+ years......

Comment: system will probably gobble quotes in ways you don't expect....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quotes around the \copy command, and nothing around your column names:

```
system(%Q{psql postgres://user:password@postgres --command "\copy (SELECT id, name FROM some_table WHERE created_at > '2019-01-22 13:40') TO STDOUT WITH CSV"})
```